# Frida - list Android processes

Tags: android, security

This question is about the security framework, Frida.  On the target Android device, why can't my Frida-Server [which is loaded onto the Android device] list the running processes?

`$ frida-ps -U` returns only the Frida-Server process ID and strangely, adb.

I am running Android 4.4.2 (32 bit O/S).
The device is rooted.

I updated the version on my host machine (not target app):

`$ sudo easy_install -U frida`

I setup the very latest Android Frida server on device dies.

```
$ curl -O https://build.frida.re/frida/android/arm/bin/frida-server
$ adb push frida-server /data/local/tmp/
$ adb shell "chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/frida-server"
$ adb shell "/data/local/tmp/frida-server &"
```

I could list the process ID of my app on the target Android device:

`$ adb shell ps | grep myapp`

I killed my Frida Server on the Android device and restarted it:

`$ kill -9 <process id>`

When I try to attach directly to the process ID `$ frida -U <process ID>` I get a permission denied message.

Answer (score 1):

Two clues helped me solve this.  The fact I could see

1. The adb process.
2. I was getting a permission error when trying to execute `$ frida -U <process ID>`

The answer was to `adb shell` into the target Android device and do a Change Ownership (chown) on the Frida-Server.

When I installed it, the Frida-Server was installed as the owner Shell.  When I changed the owner to Root, all my processes listed fine on my Mac when I ran:  `$ frida-ps -U`

The chown command was:

`/data/local/tmp # chown root frida-server`

Comment: Yep. Need to have adb running in root and always 'chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/frida-server' before running.

Answer (score 0):

Use `adb root` before you try and install the Frida Server on the Android device.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your frida-server has not enough permission
Make sure frida-server run as root, then you can list all processes

Try to do these:
1. copy frida-server to device
2. run as root on your device, and start frida-server
3. with usb connection, and run frida-ps(client frida must be same version   with frida-server)

Then you can list processes